# Get json field value by variable with jq

Tags: bash, sh, jq

I am trying to read the value of a field of a json variable, the field name is stored in a variable as well.

What I tried:

```
$ jsonVar=`cat test-config.json`
$ echo $jsonVar
{ "server-test": "xxx", "server2-test": "xxx", "server3-test": "xxx"}
$ echo $it
server-test
$ itVersion=$(jq --arg test "${it}" '.["${test}"]' <<< $jsonVar);
$ echo $itVersion
null
```

`$itVersion` should now have the value of `"server-test"` but is `null`, it seems my JQ command is wrong, but I cant figure out why.

Comment: Remove the double quotes and the `{}` from the predicate, `echo '{ "server-test": "xxx", "server2-test": "xxx", "server3-test": "xxx"}' | jq --arg test server-test '.[$test]'` works

Comment: You're welcome, I've just turned that comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is only accessible as `$var`, not `${var}`. Additionnaly, it is expanded to a quoted string, so enclosing it in double quotes is redundant.

I suggest you use the following :

```
itVersion=$(jq --arg test "${it}" '.[$test]' test-config.json)
```

Comment: To be clear, variables in the form of `${var}` are the formats used by the shell. We are not using shell variable substitution here but using jq's variables which must be in the form `$var`.